# Android studio Circular dependency

Tags: android, build.gradle

I get the following error when setting dependencies of 2 modules with android studio

Circular dependency between the following tasks:

```
:Feeds:generateDebugRFile
+--- :Feeds:generateDebugRFile (*)
\--- :login_chat:generateDebugRFile
     +--- :Feeds:generateDebugRFile (*)
     \--- :login_chat:generateDebugRFile (*)

(*) - details omitted (listed previously)
```

-----------------**login_chat.gradle** ----------

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
api project(':Feeds')

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---------------**feeds.gradle** --- --

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
api project(':login_chat')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: You want your project go into recursion building itself?

Comment: I'm no Gradle expert, but notice how both .gradle files end with an "api project" section which reference each other - have you tried commenting either of those lines?

Comment: Have you observed that this happens with instant run enabled?. Disable instant run and try to run your code again,